# How to parse numbers from a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I'm trying to understand why my regex below is failing.  I'm trying to retrieve a range of values on both sides of the `:` but my code always fails to the `else`.  `range` is coming from a command line arg like this `java -jar myprogram.jar -R 50:100`.

Is it failing because I'm passing a string to the `matches()` and looking for integers?

Here is my code:

```
private int[] parseRangeResults(String range) {
   int[] rangeResults = new int[2];

   if(range.matches("\\d+:\\d+")) {

      String[] numbers = range.split(":")
      rangeResults[0] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
      rangeResults[1] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
   } else {
      throw new Exception("Invalid Syntax.");
   }
   return rangeResults;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `numbers[2]` rather than `numbers[1]`, out of interest?

Comment: And what is your sample `range`? (For example, it matches for "123:123" for me.)

Comment: @JonSkeet my mistake, I assumed the `:` was added to the string array. I never got to that part of the code to see the failure :-P

Comment: A regex can validate a String, it doesn't parse it.  You don't even need the regex in this case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey how would I do this without the regex?

Comment: Take it out. It doesn't add any value. You are going to throw an exception anyway, possibly one more useful.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm very much a novice so I'm not questioning your judgement, but I added it in case someone passed an arg like `10a000:500000`.  If I take it out how would I verify that the data passed is correct?

Comment: @code4me See my example.  This will throw an exception like `java.lang.NummberFormatException: Unable to parse number 10a000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it like this

```
private static int[] parseRangeResults(String range) {
    String[] numbers = range.split(":", -2)
    return new int[] {Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]),Integer.parseInt(numbers[1])};
}
```

If there is no `:` it will give you an `IndexOutOfBoundException: 1`

If there is an invalid number like `1abc:234` you will get `NumberFormatException: Unable to parse 1abc`

Comment: This was my issue along with passing my function bad data.  :-/

Comment: @code4me That is where using a debugger or printing your inputs can be helpful ;)

Comment: Since this way will throw a number of exceptions, in practice, what is the best way to catch them?  I normally throw my exceptions to a custom class from the method that causes the exception.  But I'm not sure how to handle it the way you've written.

Comment: @code4me Your should only handle exceptions when you know what you want to do with them. i.e. don't do anything with the exceptions unless you know.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your handling of the output array. `String.split` removes the delimiter and does not include it in the array. Your numbers will be in `numbers[0]` and `numbers[1]`. `numbers[2]` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int[] parseRangeResults(String range) {
   int[] rangeResults = new int[2];
   if(range.matches("\\d+:\\d+")) {   
      String[] numbers = range.split(":")
      rangeResults[0] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
      rangeResults[1] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
   } else {
      throw new Exception("Invalid Syntax.");
   }
   return rangeResults;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex `"\\d+:\\d+"` for string `"asdf123:456qwerty"` will always return `true`

Use that regex instead

```
"^\\d+:\\d+$"
```

Or use exceptions

```
try{
    Integer.parseInt("asdf");
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    throw ...;
}
```

And

```
try{
    String s1 = p[0];
    String s2 = p[1];
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    throw ...;
}
```

PS. Are you sure about `numbers[2]` ?